# C# change formatting for a single DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I am creating DateTimes that are used by a third party library (on which I have of course no control).
I am using this 3rd party library to write some files, including the DateTimes I am creating.

I would like to print my dates in different format but I have no control on how the DateTime is converted by the third party and I cannot change my culture info between conversion of each DateTime, neither can I inherit DateTime to override ToString (like no one can).

Is there a way to bind a specific formatting to a DateTime so that each call to ToString method will use this formatting ?

```
DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(2013, 02, 07); //I would like this DateTime to be printed this way: 2013-02-07
DateTime secondDate = new DateTime(2013, 02, 07); //I would like this DateTime to be printed this way: Thursday, February 07, 2013

thirdPartyLib.SetFirstDate(firstDate);
thirdPartyLib.SetSecondDate(secondDate);
thirdPartyLib.PrintBothDate(); //This method convert both DateTime in strings
```

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Well if the third party writes the format and you have no means to control it, i guess you will have to read the file and make the changes then ! !

Comment: Try to decompile `PrintBothDate` and see what **exactly** is going there. What types of transformations does it use. Maybe there can be hoops, so that you can change the behavior.

Comment: Have you tried to set the default datatime format by using CultureInfo ..?

Comment: @Pandian: How does it help? A default format cannot be both of the required formats at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information given in your question, The only way you could solve this is by implementing your own printing library.

or if the 3rd party library is extendable (I doubt it since you mentioned you have no control over it) then override the `PrintBothDate()` to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about that the set datetime methods will call `ToString()` and save it with your third party library, then you can use following class

```
public static class ThirdPartyLibHelper {
    public static void SetSecondDate(DateTime dateTime) {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-Us");
        var dateTimeFormat=Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
        dateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(new[] { "" }, 'T');
        dateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(new[] { "yyyy-MM-dd" }, 'd');
        thirdPartyLib.SetSecondDate(dateTime);
    }

    public static void SetFirstDate(DateTime dateTime) {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-Us");
        var dateTimeFormat=Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
        dateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(new[] { "" }, 'T');
        dateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(new[] { "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy" }, 'd');
        thirdPartyLib.SetFirstDate(dateTime);
    }
}
```

the test code

```
DateTime firstDate=new DateTime(2013, 02, 07);
DateTime secondDate=new DateTime(2013, 02, 07);

ThirdPartyLibHelper.SetSecondDate(firstDate);
var secondDateString=secondDate.ToString();

ThirdPartyLibHelper.SetFirstDate(firstDate);
var firstDateString=firstDate.ToString();

Debug.Print("{0}", firstDateString);
Debug.Print("{0}", secondDateString);
```

If your library doesn't save the datetime as formatted string when you call `SetFirstDate()` or `SetSecondDate()`, it doesn't work.

Comment: This is a novel idea, but it's likely not to work.  Chances are that the third party library accepts a date and keeps it as a date until it outputs it.  In that case, whatever the culture info was when his `thirdPartyLib.PrintBothDate()` method runs is the one that would be used for both dates.  Also, I'd probably want to wrap this in a helper class that implements `IDisposable` so it could be used with a `using` block that sets the culture back to normal when you're done with it.

Comment: @Matt Johnson: Except the possibility it can done with this, there is almost no way to do. This question is most likely a logical error.

Comment: Agreed - The third-party library will have to support providing a custom format if the user wants that level of control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assigning to a string with the specific format);

> Each call to **ToString** method will use this formatting ?

```
string firstDate = new DateTime(2013, 02, 07).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string secondDate  = new DateTime(2013, 02, 07).ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Comment: This assumes that `SetFirstDate` and `SetSecondDate` take an `object` and not a `DateTime`. While possible, the question seems to imply that this is not the case.

Comment: `Each call to **ToString** method will use this formatting ?` this is his question.

Comment: That's only a *very* small part of the question. The important part is that `ToString` is *not* called by his code but by third party code he has no control over.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set inside a `DateTime` the format you expect to use for `ToString()` method.

`System.DateTime` is a `sealed` class which means that you cannot extend.
You can, instead, create your own Date class so that you can specify it.

```
public class DateTimeWithFormat
{

  public DateTime Date {get; set;}
  public string Format {get; set;}

  //ToString override using custom format
  public override string ToString 
   {
     return Date.ToString (Format);
     }    

 //Constructor sets date and format
  public DateTimeWithFormat( DateTime date, string format )
   {
     Date= date;
     Format = format;
    }
}
```

so that you can use this way

```
DateTimeWithFormat firstDate = new DateTimeWithFormat(
           new DateTime(2013, 02, 07),
           "yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime secondDate = new DateTimeWithFormat(
           new DateTime(2013, 02, 07),
           "dddd") ;
```

**`thirdPartyLib` must be changed to use `DateTimeWithFormat`  instead of `DateTime`**

Comment: `DateTime secondDate = new DateTimeWithFormat` will this compile?

Comment: -1: The OP clearly stated that he has no control over the third party library.

Comment: No will not compile: System.DateTime is a sealed class which means that you cannot extend. thirdPartyLib must be changed to use DateTimeWithFormat instead of DateTime

Comment: @DanielHilgarth why -1? In first statement I answer "no it's not possible" then I suggest a workaround that needs control over third party library types not third party logic.. if possible!

Comment: -1 because he *doesn't* have control over the other library, making your answer not helpful at all.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: if he doesn't have control over that library, why does he think we have? lol

Comment: @DanielHilgarth the answer to the question "Is there a way to bind a specific formatting to a DateTime so that each call to ToString method will use this formatting ?" is "No way, tirdPartyLib must be changed to use a different class instead of DateTime"; the code is to give a reason to this answer

Comment: @Kaf: He doesn't think that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible. You'll have to work around that problem:

```
thirdPartyLib.SetFirstDate(firstDate);
thirdPartyLib.SetSecondDate(secondDate);
thirdPartyLib.PrintString(firstData.ToString(firstDateFormatting)); //Assuming such a method exists
thirdPartyLib.PrintString(secondDate.ToString(secondDateFormatting));
```